# How to let xchat play a sound when someone send me messages?

Tags: linux, xchat

I know I should set the events.

I assign the sound to channel msg hilight, private message. But it doesn't work.

I set the audacious to play the file. I test it with your message event, it works fine, but the event is about sending messages.

Comment: We need much more detail. What sound are you using? Is it a wav file? MP3? OGG? Does X-Chat support the format you're trying to use? Did you specify the full path to the sound file?  Is the file readable?

Comment: @Heptite I set the audacious to play the file. I test it with your message event, it works fine, but the event is about sending messages.